# Azure DevOps Auto Prefix feature/ for feature branch and release/ for release branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Am newbie to Azure DevOps.  When a developer create branch from Integration branch, it should  auto prefix with feature/ and developer will append the jira-story-name. Similar for release branch and hot-fix branch from master. In bitbucket I was able to see some drop down from where developer used to select feature or release or hotfix. Have searched for some documents and could not able to find the settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops

Please guide me on the same.